# flutter app get stuck on the splash screen and lanchscreen.storyboard is not displaying the image

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter, dart

Yesterday, I was trying to change the launch screen image on Xcode for my flutter app. I dragged the new images to the assets.xcassets, I opened launchscreen.storyboard and the image was huge, I tried to select it, then disappeared. after that, I tried to put the delete the assets and put them again but they won't show anymore. I tried many things but nothing worked!

this is what I get when I run the app on Android studio

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           361.2s
[VERBOSE0:callback_cache.cc(133)] Could not parse callback cache, aborting restore
Configuring the default Firebase app...
Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
```

the app works just fine on android, however, on IOS, it gets stuck on the splash screen and never proceed to the app.

I tried

```
flutter update
flutter clean
flutter packages pub cache repair
rm podfile podfile.lock

WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); //on the main method
```

restarting the simulator, erasing its content, and release version of the app on a real device

is there anyway to fix this problem so that I have the launch screen and the app won't get stuck?

I am about to distribute the app, so your help would be much appreciate it!

**edit**

I solve the issue of getting stuck by going to

general>deployment info> main interface> "it was LaunchScreen and I changed it to Main"

but, still, I could not solve the second issue, (Launch images are not shown in the Launchscreen.storyboard I only see a white screen)

Comment: please answer the question and accept it so that it'll be closed

Comment: I'm facing the same issue..any fix for this?